# YUP js. return original value after validation

Tags: javascript, yup

I have some schema and I want to validate one string field which is json, but return it not as object but as a string as it comes in source data (only validate and not transform and only this particular field: others should be transformed):

```
const schema = Yup.object({
    given_name: Yup.string().min(1),
    address: Yup.object({
        country: Yup.string().oneOf(countriesList, 'Country is unknown'),
    }).json(),
})

const { address, given_name } = await schema.validate(body);
```

For example `address` comes as a string with valid json:

```
{country: "United States"}
```

The code above correctly validates address (country to be in the list), but after validation address is object and not string. I want the original string to be saved.